# How does jar signing work (conceptual) - offline systems

Tags: java, jar-signing

I'm trying to understand how java jar signing works at a high level. I know how to sign a jar, but I'm not sure how it works in terms of the validity of the key and when it needs renewed.

You included the keystore in your project and you give it the username and password ,etc. So if your key is valid for say, one more month. After that month, you go and renew it. Do you have to change the keystore in your project? What happens to JAR files that you built while the key was valid? Do they become invalid if you don't renew your key? How do machines that run your application verify the key? What if they are never online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have to change the keystore in your project?

Yes, if you renew your key, you have to import the new key and certificate into the keystore.

> What happens to JAR files that you built while the key was valid?
> Do they become invalid if you don't renew your key?

The signature of the JAR files remains valid if it was timestamped (i.e. if you used the jarsigner `-tsa` parameter), otherwise the signature becomes invalid once the certificate expires.

> How do machines that run your application verify the key? What if they are never online?

The certificate you use is itself signed by a certification authority (CA), and the machine verifying the file has a truststore containing the certificate of the CA. The machine use the CA certificate to verify your certificate, and then use your certificate to verify the signature of the file.

If the machine is offline and never updates its trustore, it may be missing new CA certificates and become unable to verify files that are seen as valid elsewhere.

Also an offline machine will be unable to fetch the certificate revocation list (CRL) and check if the certificate was revoked before its expiration date. So the verification may see a signature as valid when it's actually invalid elsewhere.